# Using genefilter on miRNA expression data

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am using genefilter as a step 1 to do differential expression analysis on R.

I am using the `pOverA` function as well as setting a filterfunction before using `genefilter()` (I have looked at the tutorials on Bioconductor).

My miRNA Expression data has no `NA`s or `NaN`s. It consists of normalized, log data and has `0` values sprinkled in-between.

I create an eset of the expression data and then:

```
ff1<-pOverA(0.2,-3.2,na.rm=TRUE)
ff2<-function(x) IQR(x) > 0.2
ff<-filterfun(ff1,ff2)
```

I now run `genefilter( exprs(miREset), ff)` and get an error message:

> Error in quantile.default(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm,
>   :    missing values and NaN's not allowed if 'na.rm' is FALSE In
>   addition: Warning message: In quantile(as.numeric(x), c(0.25, 0.75),
>   na.rm = na.rm, names = FALSE,  :   NAs introduced by coercion

I have spent a lot of time trying to understand why this is happening. I am fairly new to R.

Comment: you could also ask http://www.biostars.org/

Comment: if you have 0s in your data set,  you might be getting NaNs because some function needs to divide by a value in your dataset (and you can't divide by 0!)